# What is the right way to manage connections to mongoDB, using node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, database

I'm using node.js and mongoDB. Right now, for my test app, the connection to the db is in the main node file, but I guess this is a wrong practice.
What I want/need: a secure way (i.e. not storing password on files users can access) to connect to the db just when needed.

For example: I want several admin pages (users, groups, etc..). Each page should connect to the db, find some data, and display it. It also have a form for adding a document to the db and a delete option.

I thought maybe to create some kind of a connection function - send it what you want to do (add, update, find, delete), to where (collection name) and whatever it needs. But I can't just include this function, because then it'll reveal the password to the db. So what can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to answer your question bit by bit.

---

> Right now, for my test app, the connection to the db is in the main node file

This is fine, though you might want to put it in a separate file for easier reuse. NodeJS is a continuesly running process, so in theory you could serve all of your HTTP responses using the same connection to the database. In practice you'd want to create a connection pool, but the Mongodb driver for NodeJS already does this automatically.

---

> Each page should connect to the db, find some data, and display it.

When you issue a query on the MongoDB driver, it will automatically use a connection from its internal connection pool, as long as you gave it the credentials when your application was starting up.

---

> What I want/need: a secure way (i.e. not storing password on files users can access) to connect to the db just when needed.

I would advice to keep your application configuration (any variables that depend on the environment in which the app is running) in a separate file which you don't commit to your VCS. A module like [node-config](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config) can help a great deal with that.

---

The code you will end up with, using node-config, is something like:

**config/default.json:**

```
{
  "mongo": null
}
```

This is the default configuration file which you commit.

**config/local.json:**

```
{
  "mongo": "mongo://user:pass@host:port/db"
}
```

The local.json should be ignored by your VCS. It contains secret sauce.

**connection.js:**

```
var config = require('config');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var cache;

module.exports = function(callback){
  if(cache){
    return callback(cache);
  }
  MongoClient.connect(config.get('mongo'), function(err, db){
    if(err){
      console.error(err.stack);
      process.exit(1);
    }
    cache = db;
    callback(db);
  });
}
```

An *incomplete* example of how you might handle reusing the database connection. Note how the configuration is gotten using `config.get(*)`. An actual implementation should have more robust error handling and prevent multiple connections from being made. Using [Promises](https://promisesaplus.com/) would make all that a lot easier.

**index.js:**

```
var connect = require('./connection');
connect(function(db){
  db.find({whatever: true})
});
```

Now you can just require your database file anywhere you want, and reuse the same database connection, which handles pooling for you and you don't have your passwords hard-coded anywhere.